# Giving spaces between rows in a multicolumn table and centering the contents

Tags: multicolumn

I am making a table in latex and I want to add more space between the first and second row  ( the switching vectors and a , b ,c ) and (output voltage and Va,Vb,Vc) and also I want to have switching vectors and output voltage in the middle.
[image]

Here is the latex code :

```
\usepackage{caption}

\usepackage{array}

\usepackage{booktabs,multirow}

\begin{table}[!ht]

\centering

\vspace{1ex} 

\begin{tabular}{|c| p{0.4 cm}| p{0.4 cm}| p{0.4cm}| c | c | c |} \hline

\multirow{3}{*}{
\parbox[c]{.2\linewidth}{\centering Voltage vectors}} & 

 \multicolumn{3}{l|}{Switching vectors }&

\multicolumn{3}{c|}{Output voltage} \\ \cline{2-7}

\rule{0pt}{4ex} 

& a & b & c & Va & Vb & Vc \\ \hline

\rule{0pt}{4ex}   

V0& 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ \hline

\rule{0pt}{4ex}  

V1& 1 & 0 & 0 & 2Udc/3 & -Udc/3 & -Udc/3 \\ \hline

\rule{0pt}{4ex}  

V2& 1 & 1 & 0 & Udc/3 & Udc/3 & -2Udc/3 \\ \hline

\rule{0pt}{4ex} 

V3& 0& 1 & 0 & -Udc/3 & 2Udc/3 & -Udc/3 \\ \hline

\rule{0pt}{4ex}  

V4& 0 & 1 & 1 & -2Udc/3 &  Udc/3 &  Udc/3 \\ \hline

\rule{0pt}{4ex}  

V5& 0 & 0 & 1 & -Udc/3 &  -Udc/3 &  2Udc/3 \\ \hline

\rule{0pt}{4ex}  

V6& 1 & 0 & 1 & Udc/3 &  -2Udc/3 &  Udc/3 \\ \hline

\rule{0pt}{4ex}  

V7& 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 &  0\\ \hline

\end{tabular}

\end{table}
```

Comment: The `\rule` is acting as a `\strut`.  First, tabulars have a built in `\strut` whose size is set using \arraystretch (divide 4ex by `\ht\strutbox`).  Second, you can add a `\strut` inside a `\multicolumn` (but not in front of one).  Third, you can use, for example, `\rule[-1ex]{0pt}{4ex}` to create a `\strut` both below and above the baseline.

Comment: Welcome to [tex.se]!  If you only going to modify you coding slightly, then I suggest using the `bigstrut` package and its `\bigstrut` command to reserve more vertical space at certain points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `bigstrut` package that accompanies `multirow` you can just this command at the ends of lines that need wider spacing:

[image: First sample]

```
\begin{table}
  \centering
  \vspace{1ex}
  \begin{tabular}{|c| p{0.4 cm}| p{0.4 cm}| p{0.4cm}| c | c | c |}
    \hline
    \multirow{3}{*}{
    \parbox[c]{.2\linewidth}{\centering Voltage vectors}}
    & \multicolumn{3}{l|}{Switching vectors }
    & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{Output voltage} \bigstrut\\ \cline{2-7}
    & a & b & c & Va & Vb & Vc \bigstrut \\ \hline
    \rule{0pt}{4ex}
    V0& 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ \hline
    \rule{0pt}{4ex}
    V1& 1 & 0 & 0 & 2Udc/3 & -Udc/3 & -Udc/3 \\ \hline
    \rule{0pt}{4ex}
    V2& 1 & 1 & 0 & Udc/3 & Udc/3 & -2Udc/3 \\ \hline
    \rule{0pt}{4ex}
    V3& 0& 1 & 0 & -Udc/3 & 2Udc/3 & -Udc/3 \\ \hline
    \rule{0pt}{4ex}
    V4& 0 & 1 & 1 & -2Udc/3 &  Udc/3 &  Udc/3 \\ \hline
    \rule{0pt}{4ex}
    V5& 0 & 0 & 1 & -Udc/3 &  -Udc/3 &  2Udc/3 \\ \hline
    \rule{0pt}{4ex}
    V6& 1 & 0 & 1 & Udc/3 &  -2Udc/3 &  Udc/3 \\ \hline
    \rule{0pt}{4ex}
    V7& 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 &  0\\ \hline
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

Adjust `\bigstrutjot` via e.g. `\setlength{\bigstrutjot}{4pc}` to get different size spacing.

However, you would be better off using the ideas of the `booktabs` package you are loading:

[image: Second sample]

```
\begin{table}
  \centering
  \newcommand{\Udc}{U_{\mathrm{dc}}}
  \begin{tabular}{c *3{p{0.4cm}} *3{c}}
    \toprule
    \multirow{2}{*}{Voltage vectors}
    & \multicolumn{3}{l}{Switching vectors}
    & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Output voltage} \\
    \cmidrule(lr){2-4} \cmidrule(lr){5-7}
    & a & b & c & Va & Vb & Vc  \\
    \midrule
    V0& 0 & 0 & 0 & $0$ & $0$ & $0$ \\
    V1& 1 & 0 & 0 & $2\Udc/3$ & $-\Udc/3$ & $-\Udc/3$ \\
    V2& 1 & 1 & 0 & $\Udc/3$ & $\Udc/3$ & $-2\Udc/3$ \\
    V3& 0 & 1 & 0 & $-\Udc/3$ & $2\Udc/3$ & $-\Udc/3$ \\
    V4& 0 & 1 & 1 & $-2\Udc/3$ & $\Udc/3$ & $\Udc/3$ \\
    V5& 0 & 0 & 1 & $-\Udc/3$ & $-\Udc/3$ & $2\Udc/3$ \\
    V6& 1 & 0 & 1 & $\Udc/3$ & $-2\Udc/3$ & $\Udc/3$ \\
    V7& 1 & 1 & 1 & $0$ & $0$ & $0$ \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}
```

You can add `\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}` to this to space the lines more if you need it.  Note in this second version I have also put the voltages as math quantities so the minus sign is printed correctly.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{array,booktabs,multirow,bigstrut}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
  \centering
  \vspace{1ex}
  \begin{tabular}{|c| p{0.4 cm}| p{0.4 cm}| p{0.4cm}| c | c | c |}
    \hline
    \multirow{3}{*}{
    \parbox[c]{.2\linewidth}{\centering Voltage vectors}}
    & \multicolumn{3}{l|}{Switching vectors }
    & \multicolumn{3}{c|}{Output voltage} \bigstrut\\ \cline{2-7}
    & a & b & c & Va & Vb & Vc \bigstrut \\ \hline
    \rule{0pt}{4ex}
    V0& 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ \hline
    \rule{0pt}{4ex}
    V1& 1 & 0 & 0 & 2Udc/3 & -Udc/3 & -Udc/3 \\ \hline
    \rule{0pt}{4ex}
    V2& 1 & 1 & 0 & Udc/3 & Udc/3 & -2Udc/3 \\ \hline
    \rule{0pt}{4ex}
    V3& 0& 1 & 0 & -Udc/3 & 2Udc/3 & -Udc/3 \\ \hline
    \rule{0pt}{4ex}
    V4& 0 & 1 & 1 & -2Udc/3 &  Udc/3 &  Udc/3 \\ \hline
    \rule{0pt}{4ex}
    V5& 0 & 0 & 1 & -Udc/3 &  -Udc/3 &  2Udc/3 \\ \hline
    \rule{0pt}{4ex}
    V6& 1 & 0 & 1 & Udc/3 &  -2Udc/3 &  Udc/3 \\ \hline
    \rule{0pt}{4ex}
    V7& 1 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 &  0\\ \hline
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}


\begin{table}
  \centering
  \newcommand{\Udc}{U_{\mathrm{dc}}}
  \begin{tabular}{c *3{p{0.4cm}} *3{c}}
    \toprule
    \multirow{2}{*}{Voltage vectors}
    & \multicolumn{3}{l}{Switching vectors}
    & \multicolumn{3}{c}{Output voltage} \\
    \cmidrule(lr){2-4} \cmidrule(lr){5-7}
    & a & b & c & Va & Vb & Vc  \\
    \midrule
    V0& 0 & 0 & 0 & $0$ & $0$ & $0$ \\
    V1& 1 & 0 & 0 & $2\Udc/3$ & $-\Udc/3$ & $-\Udc/3$ \\
    V2& 1 & 1 & 0 & $\Udc/3$ & $\Udc/3$ & $-2\Udc/3$ \\
    V3& 0 & 1 & 0 & $-\Udc/3$ & $2\Udc/3$ & $-\Udc/3$ \\
    V4& 0 & 1 & 1 & $-2\Udc/3$ & $\Udc/3$ & $\Udc/3$ \\
    V5& 0 & 0 & 1 & $-\Udc/3$ & $-\Udc/3$ & $2\Udc/3$ \\
    V6& 1 & 0 & 1 & $\Udc/3$ & $-2\Udc/3$ & $\Udc/3$ \\
    V7& 1 & 1 & 1 & $0$ & $0$ & $0$ \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

This solution uses only `\arraystretch` to add vertical space.  I dropped several packages which were not being used.

```
\documentclass{standalone} 
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}
\def\arraystretch{2}%
\begin{tabular}{|c| p{0.4 cm}| p{0.4 cm}| p{0.4cm}| c | c | c |} \hline
\multirow{2}{*}{\centering Voltage vectors} &
\multicolumn{3}{l|}{Switching vectors }&
\multicolumn{3}{c|}{Output voltage} \\ \cline{2-7}
& a & b & c & Va & Vb & Vc \\ \hline
V0& 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ \hline
V1& 1 & 0 & 0 & 2Udc/3 & -Udc/3 & -Udc/3 \\ \hline
V2& 1 & 1 & 0 & Udc/3 & Udc/3 & -2Udc/3 \\ \hline
V3& 0& 1 & 0 & -Udc/3 & 2Udc/3 & -Udc/3 \\ \hline
V4& 0 & 1 & 1 & -2Udc/3 &  Udc/3 &  Udc/3 \\ \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]